# Date.now() returning server starting time instead of current time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**In my mongoose model**

```
captured_date: {
    type: Number,
    default: Date.now()
}
```

It is storing server starting time ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: No it's storing the time executed by the client application in UTC. And that is what it is supposed to be doing. Leave it alone because UTC is the right thing to store as. Especially as a "number" since millseconds since epoch does not make any sense otherwise. Or were you expecting a `Date`? In which case `type: Date`

Comment: Just solved the issue, we have to use Date.now in the place of Date.now()